# VBA using an array to avoid hard coding values to call different macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have values in column D of a sheet (Sheet2) that are derived from a formula of longer values that are automatically entered in column C thru a double-click. So, the values in columnd D is a part taken from the values in column C. On a separate sheet (Sheet5), I have a list of values in the C column of that sheet. If any of the values in column D of Sheet2 equal any of the values in column C of Sheet5, I want the cell in the F column of Sheet2 to turn red. Once the F column cell in Sheet2 is red, depending on the value in column D, I want the red colored cell to become clickable which will take the user to a different sheet listing reference values associated with the value in column D. The code below does just that. **However** I would like to avoid hard coding the different values in anticipation that some of the values which require a reference code will be added or taken away from the list in column C of Sheet5.

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range: Set c = Union(Range("D7:D446"), Range("F7:F446"))
    Dim CellF As Range, CellD As Range, Cell As Range

If Not Application.Intersect(c, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        Set CellF = Range("F" & Target.Row)
        Set CellD = Range("D" & Target.Row)

        Dim refCodes As Variant
        refCodes = Sheet5.Range("C1:C17").Value

        If CellF.Value <> "" Then
            CellF.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

            If CellD.Value = refCodes.Value Then
                CellF.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

            'Select Case CellD.Value
                         'Case "0GP", "0MM", "FEST", "IEDU", "ONLC", "PART", "PRDV", "SPPR", "DANC", "LFLC", "MEDA", "CCH", "POUBL", "GA01", "GA17", "GA99", "REDV"
                    'CellF.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            'Case Else
                'CellF.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

        End If
        End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Set sourceRange = Nothing
  If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
      Set sourceRange = Target

      Select Case Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
        Case "1000GP": gotoref1
        Case "1000MM": gotoref2
        Case "19FEST": gotoref3
        Case "20IEDU": gotoref4
        Case "20ONLC": gotoref5
        Case "20PART": gotoref6
        Case "20PRDV": gotoref7
        Case "20SPPR": gotoref8
        Case "22DANC": gotoref9
        Case "22LFLC": gotoref10
        Case "22MEDA": gotoref11
        Case "530CCH": gotoref12
        Case "60PUBL": gotoref13
        Case "74GA01": gotoref14
        Case "74GA17": gotoref15
        Case "74GA99": gotoref16
        Case "78REDV": gotoref17
      End Select
End If

End Sub
```

I thought the best way to go about avoiding hard-coding was to create an array. In the first sub you'll see the commented out snip-its of code, I tried to do that but, I am unsure of how I can call the different macros since they are associated with certain values.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Application.Run to call the macro using its string name and a Scripting Dictionary to associate the values with the Macro names.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range: Set c = Union(Range("D7:D446"), Range("F7:F446"))
    Dim CellF As Range, CellD As Range, Cell As Range

    If Not Application.Intersect(c, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Set CellF = Range("F" & Target.Row)
        Set CellD = Range("D" & Target.Row)

        If CellF.Value <> "" And getMacroDictionary.Exists(CellD.Text) Then
            CellF.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            CellF.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim key As String, dic As Object
    Set SourceRange = Nothing
    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Set SourceRange = Target
        Set dic = getMacroDictionary
        key = Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
        If dic.Exists(key) Then Application.Run dic(key)
    End If

End Sub

Function getMacroDictionary() As Object
    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("SCripting.Dictionary")
    dic.Add "0GP", "gotoref1"
    dic.Add "0MM", "gotoref2"
    dic.Add "FEST", "gotoref3"
    dic.Add "IEDU", "gotoref4"
    dic.Add "ONLC", "gotoref5"
    dic.Add "PART", "gotoref6"
    dic.Add "PRDV", "gotoref7"
    dic.Add "SPPR", "gotoref8"
    dic.Add "DANC", "gotoref9"
    dic.Add "LFLC", "gotoref10"
    dic.Add "MEDA", "gotoref11"
    dic.Add "CCH", "gotoref12"
    dic.Add "PUBL", "gotoref13"
    dic.Add "GA01", "gotoref14"
    dic.Add "GA17", "gotoref15"
    dic.Add "GA99", "gotoref16"
    dic.Add "REDV", "gotoref17"
    Set getMacroDictionary = dic
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. However, the cells in the F column do not turn red or become clickable to the user, calling the proper macro for the value in column D. I've put the code in the main sheet (Sheet2). That's where I had it originally. Should I put the entire or certain subs in a different location within the workbook? Thanks again!

Comment: @anve Everything can go into the Sheet2 code module.  I simply refactored your code.  When you change a value in `Range("$D$7:$D$446,$F$7:$F$446")` the color of the cell in the F column of the current row will turn to red if an exact match (case sensitive) is found.  Then if you select a cell in column F the matching value is Column D of the same row is used to look up the macro name that will be ran by `Application.Run`.

Comment: I think I understand now. The changing of the cell color should occur if and only if the cell value in column D isequal to the values in column C on Sheet5. So, the changing of values in Range("$D$7:$D$446") should be the deciding factor if cells in column F turn red or not. Is that how the code is setup now? Or should I adjust it to reflect that? Because I copied the refactored code you posted and it isn't turning the F column cells red which in turn isn't calling the proper macro.

Comment: The confusing part is that if you change the value of "CellF" the macro will not run until "CellF" is selected again.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the "CellF" not running until selected again.

Comment: Selection change is analogous to a control's focus event.  When a cell is selected it raises the Selection_Change event

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me. I'm a little unfamiliar with this code so if there is one sub or part of the code, that could fix this issue, what would it be? In other words, which part of code would you suggestion I alter/fix in order to get my desired result? Thanks for your help so far. I appreciate it.